# C# - Define scope for an Event Handler

Tags: c#, .net, programming-languages

I am rewriting my last question, just because I am trying to attack the problem from differente angles..

The problem is this. I have a class written in C#, with two public methods, and an eventhandler that triggers everytime any of the methods is completed.

I created this class adapting the code from a Form.

Now, if I reference this class from a Windows Process project written in VB.Net, and I call any of the two methods, the EventHandler will NOT trigger

Could this problem be related to EventHandler's scope or anything like that?

If necessary, I can post code

Thanks

++++++++++++++++++++++++
UPDATE
++++++++++++++++++++++++

Ok.. here is the code. Originally I was calling the methods from a class, but I modified the whole project just to see if the problem had to do with trying to raise the event from the class... So I have this c# webserver listening on port 8080, and upon http request calls ENROLL or IDENTIFY according to URL parameters.

Just to clarify a bit. This is a webserver that will run in a computer which has a USB fingerprint scanner connected. Then, the web application will do an http request to that computer in order to execute an IDENTIFICATION or ENROLLMENT, actions which are programmed inside the webserver, manipulating the methods included in the scanner's driver which I got with the SDK.

In have a C# demo project which came with the driver's SDK, a simple form with buttons calling ENROLL or IDENTIFY methods from the CLICK event. After the CLICK event is finished (inside of which is executed the ENROLL or IDENTIFY methods) then the Event is triggered and the EventHandler executes.

So now I have all the code in the same project, but it is still behaving the same way... it goes into the ENROLL method which executes the StartEnroll method from the WisSensorNLibLib class, but the event is not triggered nor captured by the class' custom Event Handler...

Maybe I am misplacing the definitions or the instantiations... I don't know. But the event is not triggered...

So here is the code... (and below I will paste the original Demo program code, so maybe by comparison someone can find out what the problem could be)

---

```
namespace WinServer
    {
        using System;   
        using System.IO;
        using System.Net;
        using System.Net.Sockets;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Threading;       
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.Data;           
        using System.Data.SqlClient;
        using System.Drawing; 
        //************************************
        //This is the class that belongs to the Fingerprint Scanner
        //************************************
        using WisSensorNLibLib;


    class WinServer 
    {    
        private TcpListener myListener ;
        private int port = 8080 ; // Select any free port you wish        
        private Int16 id;
        private string indx;
        //************************************
        //Create instance of WisSensorN     
        //************************************          
        WisSensorN WisObj = new WisSensorN();          
        private String mod;        
        private Int32 Rows;

        public WinServer()
        {
            try
            {
                myListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port) ;
                myListener.Start();                 
                Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartListen));
                th.Start() ;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An Exception Occurred while Listening :" +e.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void SendHeader(string sHttpVersion, string sMIMEHeader, int iTotBytes, string sStatusCode, ref Socket mySocket)
        {   
        //************************************
        //Code not related to understand specific problem was removed 
        //************************************          
        }

        public void SendToBrowser(String sData, ref Socket mySocket)
        {
        //************************************
        //Code not related to understand specific problem was removed 
        //************************************
        }  



        public void SendToBrowser(Byte[] bSendData, ref Socket mySocket)
        {
        //************************************
        //Code not related to understand specific problem was removed 
        //************************************
        }


        // Application Starts Here..
        public static void Main() 
        {
            WinServer MWS = new WinServer();
        }


        public void StartListen()
        {
        //Call ENROLL method
        Enroll();
        mySocket.Close();                       

        }


        //**********************************
        //EVENT CAPTURE
        //**********************************
        public void WisObj_DataEvent(WisSensorNLibLib.DATA data, string str)
        {

            switch (data)
            {
                //ENROLL
                case DATA.DATA_ENROLL:

                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("success"); 
                    }
                    catch (Exception ee)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ee.Message);                        
                    }                    
                    break;

                //IDENTIFY
                case DATA.DATA_IDENTIFY_CAPTURE:

                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Success");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ee)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ee.Message);                       
                    }                    
                    break;
            }
        }

        //**********************************
        //ENROLL
        //After this method ends, WisObj_DataEvent should capture the event
        //**********************************

        public void Enroll()
        {
            try
            {
                WisObj.Open();
                WisObj.DataEvent += new _IWisSensorNEvents_DataEventEventHandler(WisObj_DataEvent);
                WisObj.StartEnroll();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ee.Message);
            }
        }

        //**********************************
        //IDENTIFY
        //After this method ends, WisObj_DataEvent should capture the event
        //**********************************

        public void Identify()
        {
            try
            {
                WisObj.Open();
                WisObj.DataEvent += new _IWisSensorNEvents_DataEventEventHandler(WisObj_DataEvent);
                WisObj.IdentifyCapture();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ee.Message);
            }
        }


        public void WisClose()
        {
            WisObj.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

---

Original Demo program code:

---

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using WisSensorNLibLib;

namespace OR200N_Demo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const int MaxUser = 10;
        WisSensorN WisObj = new WisSensorN();
        string[] DB = new string[MaxUser];
        int nEnrolled = 0;
        string indx;
        string msg;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please make sure the scanner is plugged!!");
            WisObj.Open();
            WisObj.DataEvent += new _IWisSensorNEvents_DataEventEventHandler(WisObj_DataEvent);
            WisObj.SetDisplay((int)FingerPic.Handle);
        }

        private delegate void CompleteHandler(string bir);
        private void Complete(string str)
        {
            Status.Text = str;
        }

        private void WisObj_DataEvent(WisSensorNLibLib.DATA data, string str)
        {
            switch (data)
            {
                case DATA.DATA_ENROLL:
                    indx = nEnrolled.ToString();
                    msg = "User #" + indx + " is enrolled successfully!!";
                    this.Invoke(new CompleteHandler(Complete), new object[] { msg });
                    DB[nEnrolled] = string.Copy(str);
                    nEnrolled++;
                    break;

                case DATA.DATA_IDENTIFY_CAPTURE:
                    int nMatched;
                    nMatched = WisObj.Identify(str, DB);
                    if (nMatched < 0)
                    {
                        msg = "No valid finger matched!!";
                        this.Invoke(new CompleteHandler(Complete), new object[] { msg });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        indx = nMatched.ToString();
                        msg = "User #" + indx + " is matched!!";
                        this.Invoke(new CompleteHandler(Complete), new object[] { msg });
                    }
                    break;

                case DATA.DATA_VERIFY_CAPTURE:
                    break;
            }
        }
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            WisObj.Close();
        }

        private void Enroll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (nEnrolled >= MaxUser)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exceed maximum enrolled number (10)!!");
            }
            else
            {
                Status.Text = "Please put your finger on the scanner!!";
                WisObj.StartEnroll();
            }
        }

        private void Identify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Status.Text = "Please put your finger on the scanner!!";
            WisObj.IdentifyCapture();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell without seeing the code.  Can you show the C# code?

Comment: send some code, otherwise we can just guess...

Comment: Why have an event handler? Could you not use another method instead which is called at the end of both public methods.

Comment: @Ash The event handler, as you can see, is a custom handler that actually belongs to the class I am referencing from my project. I tried to solve it the way you said, but I found a problem... Once the ENROLL is executed, I can call WisObj_DataEvent with the first parameter (which tells it what type of event has been executed, an ENROLL or IDENTIFY), but I don't have the STRING with the scan result - it's a 500 characters string that is created with the scanned data - )... I guess that information is private to the class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it is *event*, not event handler, which is being raised.
Event handler is a *method that subsribes* to a given event.

Secondly, scope only governs member visibility at compile time and does not affect event subscriptions. **If event is visible, it works.**

From what you posted, one may only conclude that:

1. You may not subscribe to event in VB .NET code or may handle it incorrectly;
2. When called from VB .NET code, these methods may act differently (different parameters being passed? exeptions thrown?) and may not raise the event.

So far, this is all I can say until I see the code.
Can you trim it down to simplest reproducible case?

Comment: I tried to detail exactly what I am doing, but it was deleted by admin (too long), and I can't explain it in 500 characters... So I have no idea how to show you... Can I send you the project in a rar file so you can take a look?

Comment: @jprealini - You can't post that much code in a comment box -- instead, you need to add it to your original question.  Click the `edit` link at the bottom of the question, just under the list of tags, and you should be able to add your code (assuming it is less than 30,000 characters)

Comment: There's no point in posting the whole project, and I doubt anyone has time to dig through it. Just create an empty project with one class and try to reproduce the issue with as small code as possible.

Comment: @gaearon I added some code and explanation to the original question so you can take a look... I just saw your last comment... The code I posted is in fact the whole project. What you asked me to do is what I did with the Demo project, and it works, but the event is not being captured from my project (maybe because it is being called from an HTTP request?)... 

@Justin thanks for the tips... I am new in here, no idea how to do things right yet, but I am a fast learner... ;)

Comment: I may be wrong, but doesn't your application just die as soon as `Main` ends? You don't wait for thread to join or finish. And why do you create another thread at all? Try to keep one thread in application and narrow down the problem.

Comment: @gaearon Well... Not sure if it should die there, but it definitely does not. I run the project, and the program starts listening on port 8080. When I do an http request (go to my browser and type `http:\\mylocalip:8080` I start debugging, then I get to the `ENROLL();` call, and so on... 
And also... I don't see where I am creating a second thread... I have just one instance of the myListener object and the Thread object , just one `th.Start`placed in the constructor... am I wrong?

Comment: @gaearon Well.. if you refer to th.Start(); when you say "thread", I have no idea... In fact, the thread is started within the constructor... the constructor is not running "in" a thread...

Comment: I think you have a misconception about threads. Code always runs in a thread, and `Main` code runs in its own thread. My suggestion was to call `StartListen` from `Main` directly instead of creating a new thread. I don't think it will help but it most certainly will reduce complexity.

Comment: @gaearon Ok.. now I get it. I thought about that too . In fact, I am not sure why the program creates an instance of itself `Winserver MWS = new Winserver();` with a name that is never used again, and that is not even visible from the rest of the code. 
I tried to call the `StartListen();` from `Main`, but it seems that because of `Main` being defined as a private static method, I can't call other methods from within it's block. 
Sorry if I sound a bit confused... as I said, I'm not an expert programmer, and this is sort of advanced programming.. But I need to solve it
Thanks for your time

Comment: Please post more info about methods used. Whether `StartEnroll` blocks the thread, etc.

Comment: @gaearon in the last update to the question I posted the whole project. As I said, I joined all the methods within the same class, just in case the problem was related to calling the scanner methods from outside the class itself (but it's not).

Comment: StartEnroll does block the thread. In the original Demo project, once the method where StartEnroll is executed is closed, the WisObj_DataEvent method captures the event with the two parameters sent internally by the WisSensorNLibLib class, which are the kind of operation executed ("Data_Enroll" or "Data Identify") and a 500 character string

Comment: This code is still hard for me to grasp without being able to compile it and play with the component. Try stripping it down to simplest possible (just console app, no TCP listeners, no threads) and slowly adding features till you find what's causing the issue. Sorry, can't help you.

Comment: @gaearon I've been investigating a bit about threading, and just for testing I decided to use a Semaphore and now it's kind of starting to respond... I created the semaphore, and implemented a WaitOne(); before the call to Enroll(); and then a Release();
It's not behaving entirely as it should, but I thought this could give you a small hint about the problem and how to solve it for good.
Thanks again for your time